# Code Blocks doesn't show any error but still can't show output (0xC00000FD)

Tags: c++

I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;
main()
{
    int i, n, a[n], b[n], c[n];

    cout << "Program kreira nizove po matematickoj zavisnosti" << endl;
    cout << "Unesite vrednost n =" << endl;
    cin >> n;

    for (i = 0; i <=n; i++)
    {
        a[i] = (i+1)*2;

        if (i%2==0) b[i] = 2*i;
            else b[i] = -2*i;

        c[i] = a[i] - b[i];

    }
    cout << "A" << setw(3) << "B" << setw(3) << "C" << endl;
    cout << a[i] << setw(3) << b[i] << setw(3) << c[i] << endl;
}
```

And it shows me "Process returned -1073741571 (0xC00000FD)"
Can't find what is problem.
When I try other code, it works.
Platform is Win 10.

Comment: `0xC00000FD` means stack overflow!

Comment: `n` is not initialized before using it as the size of your arrays.

Comment: `int i, n, a[n], b[n], c[n];` what is the value of  `n`  when these non-standard arrays are allocated? Note that although `c` supports VLAs, officially `c++` does not: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
int i, n, a[n], b[n], c[n];
```

has two problems:

1. Variable length arrays are non-standard, and:
2. `n` is uninitialised so `a[n]` tries to allocate an array of some indeterminate size on the stack.  Which, in your case, is too large and is causing a stack overflow.

So, initialise `n` before you use it, and rather than using variable length arrays, use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: Ok, but I need to get message, so I can type in value of n. Do you know how I can do that?

Comment: You could put  `int a[n], b[n], c[n];` after you ask the value of `n`

Comment: You have other bugs after that. `for (i = 0; i <=n; i++)` will cause an off by 1 error. remember that a[n] is out of bounds so when i == n you are accessing one element beyond the end of the arrays.

Comment: @drescherjm No, C++ does not have VLAs. Please do not recommend this.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a non-standard variable-length array (VLA) C++ extension, and you have stack overflow because `n` is not initialized before declaring arrays like `a[n]`.

If you want to keep using VLA, need to move declaration `int a[n], b[n], c[n];`
below `cin >> n;`. Or use `std::vector<int>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Achieved to find solution... Here is the final result:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
main()
{
    int i, n, a[100], b[100], c[100];

    cout << "Program kreira nizove po matematickoj zavisnosti" << endl;
    cout << "Unesite vrednost n = ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "A" << setw(10) << "B" << setw(10) << "C" << endl;

    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        a[i] = (i+1)*2;

        if (i%2==0) b[i] = 2*i;
            else b[i] = -2*i;

        c[i] = a[i] - b[i];

        cout << a[i] << setw(10) << b[i] << setw(10) << c[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

I changed value of array to something I'll never use (like 100) and I put cout in for loop, so it can type results one under other. It managed to work perfectly. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Using fixed-length arrays instead of vectors in a situation like this is a bad habit. Don't get used to it. You can get away with it in a toy example, but not in real software.